# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: previewSize must not be taller than activeArray

Tags: android, android-camera2

My application was working good in large number of phones. However, when I installed it in my old android phone the following error is thrown and application crashes while taking the photo.

> Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: previewSize must not be
>   taller than activeArray

Photo Capturing code:

```
public class Camera1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private TextureView textureView;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private Bitmap scaled;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave1;
    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest captureRequest;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    private com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector detector;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private int width = 640;
    private int height = 480;
    private int index;
    //Image request code
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private int a=0;

    //storage permission code
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 123;

    //Bitmap to get image from gallery
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //Uri to store the image uri
    private Uri filePath;
    private String name,dl_no,truck_id, tstatus;
    private float l_value;
    private String dl;
    private int c=0;
    File fileToUpload;
    int f=0;
    private String uuid;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;
    String time1;
    String date1;
    private int mSensorOrientation;
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_camera2_api);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setMode(FaceDetector.ACCURATE_MODE)
                .build();
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            l_value=extras.getFloat("v");
            tstatus=extras.getString("status");
            name=extras.getString("name");
            dl_no=extras.getString("dl");
            truck_id=extras.getString("tid");
            latitude=extras.getString("lat");
            longitude=extras.getString("lon");
            time1 =extras.getString("t");
            date1=extras.getString("d");
        }

        fileToUpload = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "/Faceapp/"+name+"_"+dl_no+"_"+truck_id+"_"+latitude+"_"+longitude+"_"+time1+"_"+date1+"_"+a+".jpg");
        //Intent uplaod_intent = new Intent(Camera1.this, uploadRest.class);
        // Add extras to the bundle
        // Start the service
       // Camera1.this.startService(uplaod_intent);
    }

    private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
        // Sensor orientation is 90 for most devices, or 270 for some devices (eg. Nexus 5X
        // We have to take that into account and rotate JPEG properly.
        // For devices with orientation of 90, we simply return our mapping from ORIENTATIONS.
        // For devices with orientation of 270, we need to rotate the JPEG 180 degrees.
        return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createCameraPreview();
        }
    };

    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void goToCompletedActivity(Context mContext) {
        Intent login = new Intent(mContext, Completed.class);
        mContext.startActivity(login);
    }

    private void userLogin() {
        //first getting the values
        final String Driver_id = dl_no;

        class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressBar progressBar;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                try {
                    //converting response to json object
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                    //if no error in response
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //getting the user from the response
                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                        //creating a new user object
                        User user = new User(
                                userJson.getString("Driver_id"),
                                userJson.getString("Driver_name"),
                                userJson.getString("Truck_id"),
                                userJson.getString("Trainingstatus")

                        );

                        //storing the user in shared preferences
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                        //starting the profile activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Driver ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //creating request handler object
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                //creating request parameters
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Driver_id", Driver_id);


                //returing the response
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_LOGIN, params);
            }
        }

        UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
        ul.execute();

    }

    public void launchuploadservice() {
        // Construct our Intent specifying the Service
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Upload.class);
        // Add extras to the bundle
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        i.putExtra("dl", dl_no);
        i.putExtra("tid", truck_id);
        i.putExtra("lat", latitude);
        i.putExtra("lon", longitude);
        i.putExtra("status", tstatus);
        i.putExtra("t", time1);
        i.putExtra("d", date1);
        // Start the service
        startService(i);
    }

    protected void takePicture() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }

        final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int displayRotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (sensorOrientation == 90 || sensorOrientation == 270) {
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (sensorOrientation == 0 || sensorOrientation == 180) {
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));



            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null ;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        mBitmapToSave = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        if (detector.isOperational() && mBitmapToSave != null) {
                            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder()
                                    .setBitmap(mBitmapToSave)
                                    //.setImageData(buffer, width, height, YUV_420_888)
                                    //.setRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                                    .build();
                            SparseArray<Face> faces = detector.detect(frame);

                            for (index = 0; index < faces.size(); ++index) {
                                Face face = faces.valueAt(index);
                            }
                            if (faces.size() == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "No Face" + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                saveImageToDisk(bytes);
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.not);
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                               // mBitmapToSave.recycle();

                            } else {
                                saveImageToDisk(bytes);
                                Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "Face Found " + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                launchuploadservice();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                    finally {
                        if(image!=null)
                            image.close();
                    }


                }


            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    createCameraPreview();

                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

            mBitmapToSave = null;
        } catch(CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void saveImageToDisk(final byte[] bytes) {
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+"/Faceapp/"+name+"_"+dl_no+"_"+truck_id+"_"+longitude+"_"+latitude+"_"+time1+"_"+date1 + "_.jpg");
        try (final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            output.write(bytes);
            //this.picturesTaken.put(file.getPath(), bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while saving picture to external storage ", e);
        }
    }

    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Camera1.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }

        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            //image.close();
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

   // @Override
   /* public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(Camera1.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Camera1.this, Completed.class);
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");

        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }

        final int PICTURES_LIMIT = 1;

        final Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int pictureNo=0;
            public void run() {
                if (pictureNo>PICTURES_LIMIT){
                    timer.cancel();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    takePicture();
                    pictureNo++;
                }
            }

        },10, 5500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the part of your code throwing error. also check out the docs 
possibly : https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/9e9b6169a098bc19986e44fbbf65e4c29031e4bd/sdk/sources/android-22/android/hardware/camera2/legacy/ParameterUtils.java

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/9e9b6169a098bc19986e44fbbf65e4c29031e4bd/sdk/sources/android-22/android/hardware/camera2/legacy/ParameterUtils.java), its pretty self explanatory that the old device preview size is less than the size that you're trying to crop.

Check the `getPreviewCropRectangleUnzoomed` function in the code that I have mentioned above. The documentation of the function says the cause of the error specifically. From the documentation.

```
 /**
 * Calculate the effective crop rectangle for this preview viewport;
 * assumes the preview is centered to the sensor and scaled to fit across one of the dimensions
 * without skewing.
 *
 * <p>The preview size must be a subset of the active array size; the resulting
 * rectangle will also be a subset of the active array rectangle.</p>
 *
 * <p>The unzoomed crop rectangle is calculated only.</p>
 *
 * @param activeArray active array dimensions, in sensor space
 * @param previewSize size of the preview buffer render target, in pixels (not in sensor space)
 * @return a rectangle which serves as the preview stream's effective crop region (unzoomed),
 *         in sensor space
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *          if any of the args were {@code null}
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *          if {@code previewSize} is wider or taller than {@code activeArray}
 */
```

Check the part - *The preview size must be a subset of the active array size; the resulting rectangle will also be a subset of the active array rectangle.* which declares the preview size must be smaller than the actual active array size.

In this case, you might consider having a try/catch block while you are taking picture using the camera.

```
try {
    takePicture();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Your phone is too old", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: using try/catch block doesn't solve my issue look into my code and please guide further

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this may happen in very old devices with small image sensors, although seems to me (only guessing) more like a mistake by the manufacturer when they implemented the camera2 legacy wrapper.

A solution could be that when you are resolving the optimal preview size, then also to take into account that such preview size it doesn't exceed the size specified by SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE, which can be queried in the CameraCharacteristics:

[CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE)