# PreviewSize must not be taller than activeArray

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using  googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic  when i use back camera there is no problem when i switch it to front Facing it throws Fatal Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: previewSize must not be taller than activeArray
```

Please help me regarding i was stuck here for long time.

Comment: show code snippet..

Comment: I am using the same code present at 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java

Comment: increase your preview height and width.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta my code is present at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942403/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-previewsize-must-not-be-taller-than

Comment: @HemantParmar How to increase preview height and width for front facing camera

Comment: look your example which you have share, there is field for preview height and width.

Comment: @HemantParmar do i need to set them in  onSurfaceTextureAvailable() method.